# Search for a value in a column and use the row number obtained to copy a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to search for a value in a column and using the row number obtained I want copy a cell.
Here's my code.

```
If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("Details").Range("A:A") 'searches all of column A
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        x = Rng.Row
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("Details").Activate
            Sheets("Details").Range("Hx").Copy
            Sheets("Report").Activate
            .Range("A6").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Else
            MsgBox "Unique ID Doesnot Exist! Please Check Again." 'value not found
        End If
    End With
End If
```

How to get the value of x and refer to the cell in column H with the row number obtained from the search?

Thanks

Comment: `Sheets("Details").Range("H" & x).Copy`, but you also need to move the `x = Rng.Row` *after* the `If Not Rng Is Nothing Then`.

Comment: It Worked. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

To close the question: variables don't belong inside quotes. Concatenate with `&`:

```vb
Sheets("Details").Range("H" & x).Copy
```

Also, you need to move the `x = Rng.Row` *after* the `If Not Rng Is Nothing Then`.